# Font-size classes and nested html

Tags: html, css, font-size

I've got a problem with CSS inheritance. Here's a simplified version of my stylesheet, where I am trying to control font-sizes in nested divs for my web-app :

#### CSS:

```
.type-small {
    font-size: 24px;
}
.type-large {
   font-size: 48px;
}

.type-small .btn {
   font-size: 24px;
   height: 28px;
}
.type-large .btn {
   font-size: 48px;
   height: 82px;
}
```

When you look at this sample HTML, the innermost `type-small` isn't used to format the "Save" button. It looks like CSS is picking up the classes irrespective of which is deeper nested in the HTML.

#### HTML

```
<div class="type-small">
  <div class="type-large">
    <button class="btn">Refresh</button>
    <div class="type-small">
      <p>Sample info </p>
      <button class="btn btn-inverse">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Take a look at this JSFiddle for an interactive version. Is there any arrangement of the CSS that would make this work (at scale)?

http://jsfiddle.net/HA5zy/

Answer (score 3):

The inheritance ( specificity ) of

```
.type-large .btn { /* line 29 */
    font-size: 48px;
    height: 82px;
}
```

is greater than

```
.type-small .btn { /* line 25 */
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 28px;
}
```

When you mention *"CSS is picking up the classes irrespective of which is deeper nested in the HTML."* well, it's not the way it works.

To make it short, because your 2 declarations have the same weight, the one written AFTER in your css file will take precedence and be applied.

You can correct your situation by giving more specificity to your declarations like so:

```
.type-small .btn, .type-large .type-small .btn { /* enhence the weight */
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 28px;
}
```

Take note that the use if !important is discouraged and will lead you to another kind of problem sooner or later, like having the oposite html construction where you'll have a .type-large inside a .type-small.

One other thing, *this point was raised by user Lucky Soni*, you should consider constructing with minimum markups. Meaning, your whole html could be reformated to something like this :

```
<button class="type-large btn">Refresh</button><br/>
<p class="type-small">Sample info </p><br/>
<button class="type-small btn">Save</button>
```

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/HA5zy/4/)

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity for more details and a better comprehension of cascading style.

> 6.4.1 Cascading order
>
> To find the value for an element/property combination, user agents
>   must apply the following sorting order:
>
> Find all declarations that apply to the element and property in question, for the target media type. Declarations apply if the
>   associated selector matches the element in question and the target
>   medium matches the media list on all @media rules containing the
>   declaration and on all links on the path through which the style sheet
>   was reached.
>
> Sort according to importance (normal or important) and origin (author, user, or user agent). In ascending order of precedence:
>
> > - user agent declarations
> > - user normal declarations
> > - author normal declarations
> > - author important declarations
> > - user important declarations
>
> Sort rules with the same importance and origin by specificity of selector: more specific selectors will override more general ones.
>   Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes are counted as normal elements and
>   classes, respectively.
>
> **Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins**.
>   Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any
>   declarations in the style sheet itself.

Comment: I thought that was how the CSS was chosen, but not positive, and now I know. Is there any way to not put any other class on the `button` but have it somehow inherit the `type-small` class and forget about the `type-large`?

Comment: I proposed a solution in answer by raising the weight of your css declaration. ( .type-large .type-small .btn {} )

Answer (score 1):

Why use additional markup just to apply these simple classes?

Modify your markup like:

```
<div class="type-small">
    <button class="type-large btn"></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.type-small {
 font-size: 24px;
}
.type-large {
 font-size: 48px;
}

.type-small.btn {
 font-size: 24px;
 height: 28px;
}
.type-large.btn {
 font-size: 48px;
 height: 82px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7nzv/1/

Comment: The `type` classes are used for the content and we are looking for the buttons to inherit the closest type style.

Answer (score 1):

```
.type-small {
    font-size: 24px;
}
.type-large {
   font-size: 48px;
}

.type-small>.btn {
   font-size: 24px;
   height: 28px;
}
.type-large>.btn {
   font-size: 48px;
   height: 82px;
}
```

Just specify that the .btn is an immediate child of the .type-x with the '>'.

Comment: The way that we're using the classes in the app, the `.btn`'s aren't always an immediate child of the `.type-small`

Answer (score 0):

Change your third class to this: (Notice the addition of "button")

.type-small button.btn {

Comment: With Bootstrap, we can also use the `.btn` class on `div` and `a` tags, so we're not looking to be specific in that sense with the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add the !important attribute like this:

```
.type-small .btn {
    font-size: 24px!important;
    height: 28px!important;
}
```

Comment: This makes both buttons have the class of `type-small` when what we're looking for is for each `button` to inherit the closest `type` class which in this sample the first button would get the `type-large` class and the second button would get the `type-small` class.